# Swiftui [BUG] NavigationView and List not showing on iPad simulator only

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

## Blank page on all kinds of iPad simulator

Go to Apple developer website to download tutorials project below:

https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation

Run this on any iPad simulator, you will just get a blank page, but the code works fine on simulator of Mac/iPhone and my real iPhone device.

This is definitely a bug, and I've reported to Apple, I am posting here just want ppl like me who said this issue, pls don't waste your time on reset simulator, checking your code, restart your laptop, wait until apple to fix this.

### Screenshot

[image]

### Sample code from Apple SwiftUI tutorials project:

```
import SwiftUI

struct LandmarkList: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(landmarkData) { landmark in
                NavigationLink(destination: LandmarkDetail(landmark: landmark)) {
                    LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Landmarks"))
        }
    }
}

struct LandmarkList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ForEach(["iPhone SE", "iPhone XS Max"], id: \.self) { deviceName in
            LandmarkList()
                .previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: deviceName))
                .previewDisplayName(deviceName)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to answer of @Procrastin8, I am here to show the example code, you just need to add one line of code `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle()`

```
import SwiftUI

struct LandmarkList: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(landmarkData) { landmark in
                NavigationLink(destination: LandmarkDetail(landmark: landmark)) {
                    LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Landmarks"))
        }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

struct LandmarkList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ForEach(["iPhone SE", "iPhone XS Max"], id: \.self) { deviceName in
            LandmarkList()
                .previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: deviceName))
                .previewDisplayName(deviceName)
        }
    }
}
```

### Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 12):

It's actually working just fine. By default, on iPad, the `navigationStyle` of a `NavigationView` means that you are seeing the *detail* view with a collapsed *master* view. Try rotating device or simulator and you will then see your master list. Selecting an item will push that onto the detail view. Or, swipe right from the left edge and your list will appear.

Don't like this behavior? You can set your navigation view's `navigationStyle` to `StackNavigationViewStyle()`. It will only show a single view on top at any given time.

I can't currently find an option to always show the master view as that is currently how my app is configured using a `UISplitViewController`. It is likely a temporary situation.

Comment: Hi @Procrastin8, yes, rotate device will see the view, but this is still not fine for me, it is acting kind weird. Adding `StackNavigationViewStyle()` is a solution, but the whole view is not portrait anymore, does not meet my design requirements. but your answer is showing stuff, thanks for that.

Comment: Hi @Procrastin8, do you have other style we can try ? Using `StackNavigationViewStyle()` makes the UI looks not nice on Mac and iPad which has bigger screen. I like the original style

Comment: Customization is seriously lacking right now. If you truly need this behaviour (which to me is reasonable!) you need to wrap a `UISplitViewController` as a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` and do it by hand. Hopefully Apple addresses a lot of these deficiencies soon.

Answer (score 1):

When I first saw my app on the iPad I was also put off. But then I realized it makes sense not to waste all the screen on a `List`, so I show the first item in a detail view by default:

```
var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                // Main view (by default shows on iPhone but not on iPad)
                VStack{
                    List {
                        ForEach(viewModel.arPictures,  id: \.date) { potd in
                            NavigationLink(destination: POTDDetailView(potd: potd)) {
                                Text(potd.title ?? "")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Last 8 days pictures"), displayMode: .inline)
                
                // Detail view (by default shows on iPad but not on iPhone)
                if (!viewModel.arPictures.isEmpty){
                        POTDDetailView(potd: viewModel.arPictures[0])
                }
                
            }
    }
```

[image]