# Swift: Preview on Device fails with "Error encountered when sending 'display' message to agent."

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, preview

I am trying to get a device preview running on my **iPad Pro (4th Gen.)** running **iOS 14.3**. My MacBook Pro is running **macOS Big Sure v11.2.1** and **Xcode (Version 12.4 (12D4e))**.

I am using a project provided by Apple (SwiftUI Tutorial). You can download the project profiles here: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation

When I want to preview this project, the iPad runs Preview, the App opens as far as I can see but the screen remains white.

The Error I am receiving:

```
RemoteHumanReadableError: Failed to update preview.

Error encountered when sending 'display' message to agent.

==================================

|  RemoteHumanReadableError
|  
|  LoadingError: failed to load library at path "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5C0603D6-DFAC-4045-AEB5-1F52FE81F045//tmp/E035A269-7512-4B63-A05C-26D2BF6E4226-ContentView.2.preview-thunk.dylib": Optional(dlopen(/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5C0603D6-DFAC-4045-AEB5-1F52FE81F045/tmp/E035A269-7512-4B63-A05C-26D2BF6E4226-ContentView.2.preview-thunk.dylib, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
|   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5C0603D6-DFAC-4045-AEB5-1F52FE81F045/tmp/E035A269-7512-4B63-A05C-26D2BF6E4226-ContentView.2.preview-thunk.dylib: code signature invalid for '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5C0603D6-DFAC-4045-AEB5-1F52FE81F045/tmp/E035A269-7512-4B63-A05C-26D2BF6E4226-ContentView.2.preview-thunk.dylib'
|  )
```

I can't imagine that this is caused by a bug from Apple, so I wonder how I could fix this. I would appreciate any help a lot.

Comment: Problems with Preview are common. Depending on the type of problem the only fix is to restart Xcode. But I've had problems too when using Environment objects or dealing with ViewRepresentables.

Comment: I think your issue is the same as this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59338711/swiftui-bug-navigationview-and-list-not-showing-on-ipad-simulator-only

Comment: Thanks @MiguelLomelí I tried to restart Xcode which unfortunately didn't help. The error message occurs consistently, sometimes with a "updating preview took more than 5 sec." error. I am pretty new to to swift and Xcode. Is there anything else I can do or anybody else I can direct to, that could help?

Comment: Btw, when I turn off preview, the app itself that was installed on my iPad runs perfectly fine.

Comment: Do you want to Preview the Views only or experiment with the interaction? I find previewing Views is faster, so I don't know if there's a Resource limit. Also complex Views tend to fail more, so you can experiment dividing it into more files. However if you want to make sure there isn't anything wrong with your XCode, I'd run a simple Hello World View and see if you can preview it.

Comment: In a later step I want to use ARKit where I will need the camera of the iPad. That’s why I want to preview on a real device. 
Unfortunately, the preview also doesn’t work with a simple Hello World Application :(

Answer (score 0):

I have a part answer to my problem. Instead of starting the real device preview from the preview panel on the right, I chose the play button on the top left. This way, you have to restart the preview every time you made changes and want to see them on the real device but at least building and previewing is fast.

Make sure that your connected device at the top bar is selected (on the screenshot it is not, you can see that because of the blue icon)

[xcode real device preview screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YY27.jpg)